# C#: FileSystemWatcher only dispatches ChangedEvent

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I am working with the FileSystemWatcher construct in C#.  As par for the course, I am making my watchers only watch directories of interests.  The problem I am having is that regardless of the user event (copy, create, rename) the only event I am picking up is the Changed event.

For example.

1. Watch file "C:...\Desktop\MattsRequest"
2. Create File "C:...\Desktop\MattsRequest\Dummy.txt"
3. Observe that only the OnChanged handler is triggered with a FileSystemEventArg of "Changed" and the path arg is "C:...\Desktop\MattsRequest" **and no mention of what file was created**

My watcher code looks like so.

```
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            //watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.InternalBufferSize = 32768 * 2;
            //Can't use a synchro because I can't find an example of something that
            //implements ISynchroniz-whatever
            //watcher.SynchronizingObject =

            watcher.Path = filePath;

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                    | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                    | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;  //Gets triggered
            watcher.Created += OnCreated;  //Never triggered
            watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;  //Never triggered
            watcher.Error += WatcherOnError; //Never triggered

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Below is an image of when I have created a new file in the watched directory, and the event that it fires off.  It's of course of type Changed, but it doesn't tell me which file was created.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you watch top level directory. For example you watch "Desktop\MattsRequest" but you create file in subdirectory "Desktop\MattsRequest\MattsRequest\Dummy.txt".

Comment: And if you want to track changes in subdirectories too - set `watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;`

Comment: @Evk Hello Evk.  You were EXACTLY correct on what the issue was.  Would you mind making your comment a response so I can give it a green check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen when you watch a directory and create a file inside subdirectory of that directory. That is because creating a file in a directory changes that directory's timestamp, and that is the event you see (change of the directory).

To fix - either watch subdirectory itself, or set `watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;` to include subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Evk's answer was the correct one.  I was watching the grandparent folder only, and that folder fired off an event which was missing the information.  Once I added a watcher to the parent folder, the Created and other events were fired off correctly.